# two elements - one click, another hover, one function

Tags: jquery, click, hover

Im trying to make button1 and button2 have each trigger, but same function.

Something like this:

```
$("#button1").hover,$("#button2").click (function () {...
```

Comment: just a reminder: if you've found one of the answers below helpful, then please except the one that you found most helpful by clicking the check mark near that answer. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The function parameter can take in a pointer to a function.

so:

```
$("#button1").hover(DoSomething);
$("#button2").click(DoSomething);

function DoSomething() {
     //does something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.bind()` which allows you to bind multiple events to an object.

```
$(obj).bind('hover, click',function(e){.....})
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uc9W9/

EDIT:::

use `.on()` instead if you are using newer versions of jquery as `.bind()` may not be used in future versions of jquery

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uc9W9/1/

Comment: This is a neat way to approach it. The only change I would suggest is to use .on() instead of .bind().

Comment: @mccow002 ah you are right since jquery may not use bind in future versions...updating my answer now

Answer (score 0):

You could better define a event handler function once and bind the same in both the events.

```
var callback = function() { ... }
$('#button1').hover(callback);
$('#button2').click(callback);
```